# Why is FileReader.onload handler set with a self executing function

Tags: javascript, filereader

Following the code [MDN for using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications):

```
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
      continue;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is a the div output where the content will be displayed.

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

focusing on this line:

```
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
```

What is the reason behind the self executing function? I understand that the *img* is passed to the function and used inside the method of the returning function, but why do they not just reference it like so:

```
reader.onload = function(e) { img.src = e.target.result; };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special scope in a `for` loop, so declaring variables inside the loop will overwrite the variable on each iteration, so this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(img);
    }, 100);

}
```

will log the **last** image only, ten times.

The same way that `setTimeout` is async, `reader.onload` is also async, it executes the callback at a later time, so because the img variable is incorrectly defined inside the loop a closure is needed to create a new scope to lock in the value of `img`, and it could have just as well been written

```
(function(aImg) {

    reader.onload = function() {
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
    }

})(img);
```

someone just decided to be a little clever and write an IIFE that lock in the value of `img` in each iteration with an IIFE that returns a function.

In other words, if they just referenced it without the IIFE they would end up with the last `img` only, as the for loop would complete and overwrite the `img` variable on each iteration, and the onload function executes later, when the loop has completed and `img` holds the last value set only.